# How can I implement the bottom navigation bar into an app for android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigationbar

Here is a piece of Java code. 
The Android app stops when I tap on an item in the `BottomNavigationView`, it should open a fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
       private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can have a number of possible execution paths:

```
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.item0:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new Item0_Fragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item1:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new Item1_Fragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item2:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new Item2_Fragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item3:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new Item3_Fragment()).commit();

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

            });
        }
```

Comment: is `content` the id of your parent layout?

Comment: content is the id of the parent layout (frame layout)

Comment: add your full error stack.

Comment: can you plz post your layout xml & menu.xml file

Answer (score 0):

First, you did declares two times the BottomNavigationView. In second, you not writed the complete code, leaving aside parts that may be important. However I did write a code for this. Try read my code or just copy and paste. You just need create your fragments, if needs help to do this let me know.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

List<Fragment> fragmentList;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(TAG,"onCreate()");

    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(new Fragment1());
    fragmentList.add(new Fragment2());

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerAppActivity);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(botNavViewItemSelectedListener());

}

public BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener botNavViewItemSelectedListener() {
    return new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.itemFragment1:

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;

                case R.id.itemFragment2:

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerAppActivity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_bar_item_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_bar_item_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

menu_bottom.xml to populate my menu of navigation

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/itemFragment1" android:title="Frag1" android:enabled="true" app:showAsAction="always|withText" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/itemFragment2" android:title="Frag2" android:enabled="true" app:showAsAction="always|withText" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

*For fragment click this http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/

*For activities

Following code makes the bottom navigation for activites(same feel as to fragment)

STEP 1: Create a BaseActivity and name it as BaseActivity

`BaseActivity.java`

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

protected BottomNavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentViewId());

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigationView);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateNavigationBarState();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.menuBuilding) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityA.class));
    } else if (itemId == R.id.menuChat) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
    } else if (itemId == R.id.menuProfile) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class));
    }
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    finish();
    return true;
}

private void updateNavigationBarState() {
    int actionId = getNavigationMenuItemId();
    selectBottomNavigationBarItem(actionId);
}

void selectBottomNavigationBarItem(int itemId) {
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0, size = menu.size(); i < size; i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        boolean shouldBeChecked = item.getItemId() == itemId;
        if (shouldBeChecked) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            break;
        }
    }
}

abstract int getContentViewId();

abstract int getNavigationMenuItemId();
}
```

STEP 2:
Create a child activity and name it as ActivityA and copy paste the following code

`ActivityA.java`

```
public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity implements {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
int getContentViewId() {
    return R.layout.activity_a_layout;
}

@Override
int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
    return R.id.menuBuilding;
}
}
```

Similary create `ActivityB.java` and `ActivityC.java` .Make both classes similar to ActivityA.java.But the different is `ActivityA.java` returns

```
@Override
  int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
     return R.id.menuBuilding;
 }
```

and

`ActivityB.java` returns

```
@Override
int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
    return R.id.menuChat;
}
```

and

`ActivityC.java` returns`

```
@Override
int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
    return R.id.menuProfile;
}
```

Also create layout for two java class and copy paste the `activity_a_layout.xml` code to both layouts of `ActivityB.java` and `ActivityC.java`

STEP 3 : Create a layout named activity_a_layout and copy paste the following code

'activity_a_layout.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 >


 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
  android:background="@android:color/white">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Coming soon..."
      android:textSize="19sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<include
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

STEP 4:

Create a layout named bottom_navigation and copy pase the following code

`bottom_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_menu_selector"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_menu_selector"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
```

STEP 5: Create a menu folder inside res and create a file named bottom_nav_items inside menu and copy paste the below code

`bottom_nav_items.xml`

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuChat"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
    android:title="Chat" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuBuilding"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_building_white"
    android:title="Company" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuProfile"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_item_profile"
    android:title="Profile"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/transparent" />
</menu>
```

**Dont forgot to declare `ActivityA.java`,`ActivityB.java` and `ActivityC.java` in manifest

HAPPY CODING