# How can i use bottom navigation view referring to fragments and activities?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I want to implement logic to my BaseActivity.java where I can switch between activities and fragments.

I came upon only for solutions with only fragments: https://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/ or only activities:
[How can I implement the bottom navigation bar into an app for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604239/how-can-i-implement-the-bottom-navigation-bar-into-an-app-for-android)
How can I implement the bottom navigation bar into an app for android?

but I don't know how to combine them

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" >

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/primary_icon_color"
            app:itemRippleColor="@color/primary_icon_color_super_light"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_icon_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to create a menu folder in res and create a new file named navigation.xml, You can adjust according to your needs. Below is a sample code in navigation.xml that I use:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_home"
    android:title="Dahboard" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_category"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_wallet"
    android:title="E-Wallet" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_promo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_promo"
    android:title="Promo" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_wishlist"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_no_favorite"
    android:title="Wishlist" />
```

because you have called bottom navigation in BaseActivity Layout then you just need to add some code in OnCreate Block code in your BaseActivity.java:

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pager_number);
    createNotificationChannel();
    getToken();
    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_category:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_promo:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_wishlist:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = navigation.getMenu().getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

and then you can add this code bellow your onCreate Block code:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new EwalletFragment();
            case 2:
                return new PromoFragment();
            case 3:
                return new WishlistFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pager_number;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to initialize variable abovr onCreate Block code:

```
public BottomNavigationView navigation;
public ViewPager viewPager;
MenuItem prevMenuItem;
int pager_number = 4;
```

**EDIT: **

If you want to move to another activity, you just need to add an intent in one of the case.

For example I want the bottom navigation with id navigation_wishlist to move to SettingActivity when clicked.

```
                case R.id.navigation_wishlist:
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                return true;
```

I hope the above solution can solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't your Android studio screams that its unable to use switch statement on IDs?

Comment: also this solution is for fragments only. I wish to switch between fragments and two activities

Comment: Hi arianwww, you can use ID in the switch statement.

Yup, the code above will run pretty well if you want to move between fragments using bottom navigation.

If you want to move to another activity, you just need to add an intent in one of the cases.                 case R.id.navigation_wishlist:
                            Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                    return true;

Comment: Cek my answer above, i already adding new block code for solving your problem about switching between fragment to activity using bottom navigation.